# Kotlin arrow.kt - Option.getOrElse is accepting other type than T

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

I am trying to use the Option.getOrElse() method.

According to the source:

```
inline fun <R> fold(ifEmpty: () -> R, ifSome: (A) -> R): R = when (this) {
  is None -> ifEmpty()
  is Some<A> -> ifSome(t)
}

fun <T> Option<T>.getOrElse(default: () -> T): T = fold({ default() }, ::identity)
```

But when I call getOrElse with a lambda that returns a value of type other than type `T`, it does not show any error compile time or runtime.

```
val value1 = Some("val")

// No error
value1.getOrElse { true }
```

It does not seem right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't assign the result to any variable, so Kotlin probably infers that what you want is an Any. Assign it to a String, and it won't compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `Option` is [covariant](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) (you can see it's declared as [`Option<out A>`](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/blob/master/modules/core/arrow-core-data/src/main/kotlin/arrow/core/Option.kt#L10)), so `value1` is *also* an `Option<Any>` and `{ true }` is inferred to be `() -> Any`.